# Should we avoid internetisms like TL;DR?

Tags: discussion

I saw an answer to an old question today which included a jokey [**TL;DR**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl;dr) at the top.

This StackExchange isn't superuser or webapps. Arguably we are reaching out to an audience which doesn't necessarily spend a lot of time on the internet and may not be familiar with usenet style jargon and internet memes.

So should we think about editing that kind of thing out of our content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that a good chunk of our audience are not avid internet users and hence, might not be aware of such terms. I would actually be for removing them. Perhaps we can replace it with **"Summary"** or an equivalent.